# Yii2 redirect to previous page

Tags: yii2

Now My application is using gridview to list all information and it's also have pagination.when the user click on pagination number and then click on edit and then save. It redirect user to view page. What I want to do it to redirect user to previous page(url with pagination number).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You could use `Yii::$app->request->referrer` which returns the last page the user was on.

Usage is straightforward:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

You need also take into account that `referrer` can be `null`:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
```

See [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$referrer-detail).

Comment: Second example can be shortened to `return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);`

Comment: but referrer URL is not got when we reached from one URL which is not accessed by the guest. I think it can get by return URL but how can I manage the referral url and return url.

Answer (score 12):

[Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4343) it says that it's a good practice to check if `referrer` is set at the first place.
So if you use the following code you will be redirected to last page if referrer is set or to your configured `homeUrl` if the return URL was not set previously.

```
return $this->goBack((!empty(Yii::$app->request->referrer) ? Yii::$app->request->referrer : null));
```

[goBack() details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#goBack()-detail)

[redirect details](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect()-detail)

Answer (score 2):

It is true what @Kostas says, but I think it would be better if you simply code the following, because goBack take account of a null parameter already to goBack HOME.

```
return $this->goBack(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

I tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Html::submitButton` when you are in a form and you want to be redirected to the previous page, so mostly to your module list I recommend using `use yii\helpers\Url;`:

```
return $this->redirect(Url::previous('previous') ?: ['list']);
```

because

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

will return you back to the form instead of a module list.