# How to return to previous page after update a record?

Tags: url, yii2, updates

I use Yii2 and I have this problem. This is my Update action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
      $searchModel = new AutoriSearch();
      $searchModel1 = new EditoriSearch();
      $searchModel2 = new LuoghiSearch();
      $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
      $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
      $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->IDBibliografia]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2
        ]);
    }
```

I want, after saving, to return to the previous page. So the problem is in redirect raw. So, I click the button from the index, to go to the update action. Then, when I save the update, I want to return to index (but it need to be the same previous page with the same previous Url). I found various solution on Stack, but anything can help me.
I need help, thank you!!!!

Comment: Duplicate of [yii2 back to previous page after update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40505215/57091)?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
```

maybe duplicate of [Yii2 redirect to previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554211/yii2-redirect-to-previous-page)

if you need to capture the url *before previous*, you might use yii2's sessions to store the referrer in **actionUpdate** like so (e.g. to capture search params and page no from index):

```
Yii::$app->session->set('url', Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
```

and redirect after save:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->session->get('url', ['view', 'id' => $model->IDBibliografia]));
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the solution. This return to the index, but at the first page. I want to come back to the previous page. For example, if I activate the update action from the index page 4, I want, after saving, to come back at the page 4.

Comment: that's what i tried to explain. store the referrer (e.g. index/?page=4) in the session within the *update* action (the action, which *renders* the form, and *not* stores the data). so if you update item #101 from page #4 and redirect to your edit form, remember the referrer for later use.